# Checking if a certain div is in viewport or not

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I have a scrollable table with thousands of rows. How can i check which rows are in the viewport?

Comment: Try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. Polyfill (https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/gh-pages/polyfill)

Comment: Is the row height constant, or each row has a different height?

Comment: @RomanCortes the rows height is constant

Answer (score 0):

If the row height is constant, then it should be easy to compute:

```
firstVisibleRowIndex = Math.floor(rowHeight / scroll);
lastVisibleRowIndex = Math.ceil(rowHeight / (scroll + tableHeight));
```

- tableHeight must be the height of the visible area, not the full table.
- I assume all sizes are in the same unit, pixels.
- If I did the math right, the rows visible include both the first and last visible rows

Comment: I forgot to mention that this solution should perform really good compared to iterating over all elements and checking their boundaries, this is thanks to having a fixed height